# Mathemmatical formula for incremental breakdowns

Tags: javascript, python, increment

I have a dialog that displays buttons according to users settings.
I want to have the buttons layed out in the best sequence of rows of 6.
Meaning, if the user entered 1-6 entries, there should be 1 row of 6 buttons.
If he entered 7 entries, it shouldn't be 6 on row 1 and 1 on row 2, rather, 4 on row 1 and 3 on row 2.
If he entered 8, it should have 4 buttons on each row
And so on.....

Being that I am a somewhat seasoned developer, I feel a little dumb by this.... but I am having difficulty figuring out the correct method of finding out these numbers programmatically.

If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it

Thanks,
David

Comment: We're going to have a hard time programmatically finding those numbers too, if the programming language isn't tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a / b` is integer division and `a % b` is the remainder of the division of `a` by `b`, then you will need

```
rows = (buttons + 5) / 6
```

rows of buttons. Now you can just divide by the number of rows to find the best partitioning. If you want to minimize the absolute difference of row lengths, the i-th line (zero-based) could for example contain

```
buttons_in_line[i] = buttons / rows + (i < buttons % rows ? 1 : 0)
```

buttons. E.g. For 22 buttons you would get the following layout:

```
# # # # # #
# # # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
```

Or for 19 buttons:

```
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few solutions here. The basic idea is finding out how many rows you need, then averaging the number of buttons per row.  The trick then is dealing with uneven rows.

```
rows = buttons/row_limit;
buttons_per_row = buttons/rows;
```

You could then add buttons to rows and keep track of the remainder, or use some sort of recursive function that deals with the remaining buttons.

```
button_remainder = 0;
for(row in rows)
    row_buttons = math.floor(buttons_per_row);
    buttons -= row_buttons;

    button_remainder += buttons_per_row - row_buttons;
    if(button_remainder >= 1)
        row_buttons++;
        buttons--;

    row.setButtonCount(row_buttons);
```

The recursive function is similar, but it doesn't keep track of the fractional remainder of a button.

Comment: @ Nikias - Thanks. Works great! exaclty what I was looking for.
Can you just explain what the +5 does?

@Bracket - Thanks for the effort. I was looking for something more like nikias' solution.